# Filling a gap in a sentence

Tags: articles, idioms

I have this text with a gap to fill :

> Also, once you've reached a good enough standard to join a band or orchestra, you develop the team skills similar to those you get from playing sport. And finally, there is a great social side ___ playing with others, as well as the chance to travel, through touring.

Intuitively, I know that there should be a word "to", but I can't say exactly why it is that way. Is it an idiom, or a saying?

Answer (score 2):

There's an idiomatic expression *There are two sides to every question*, and according to the [Oxford Collocations Dictionary](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=side) the noun"side" (as *an aspect/quality of somebody/something*) collocate with the preposition *to*:

> There are several sides to most problems.

So, I think that answering the question "Why is it that way?", you could say "Because it's a set phrase (a collocation)".

Your gut feeling didn't betray you.

Comment: This answer would get an upvote from me if it included a link to the Oxford Collocations Dictionary.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Oxford Collocations Dictionary for Students of English, second edition, Oxford University Press, ISBN: 9780194325387, p.761, "side" 4.

Comment: Hi, Rompey. Thanks for the information. I was talking about a link to the [online version](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=side), so people could look at it, just as in the case you had referenced an online dictionary.

Comment: @ AlanCarmack Hi, I have just found the [link](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=side)